# Polygon see mempool?

Tags: polygon, txpool, full-node

In Eth, you need to run a full node to see the mempool. I want to see the mempool in real time faster than a provider -- do I need to do a full node for Polygon as well?

Comment: Yes, either you need to run a full-node or use a hosted service that provides an RPC for their full-nodes. But probably it will be faster if you host your own.

Answer (score -1):

Actually you need to use the full node in order to see the mempool. Similarly like Ethereum, But obviously Polygon will be fast.
Or you can use third-party APIs to access the mempool.

Read here: [https://www.blocknative.com/blog/monitor-polygon-mempool#:~:text=The%20mempool%20is%20the%20strongest,to%20be%20confirmed%20on%2Dchain.](https://www.blocknative.com/blog/monitor-polygon-mempool#:%7E:text=The%20mempool%20is%20the%20strongest,to%20be%20confirmed%20on%2Dchain.)